# Get audit logs of a specific user [discord rest api]

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I am trying to get the actions from audit log of a specific user. This is the official documentation about that: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/audit-log#get-guild-audit-log

```
import requests

url="https://discord.com/api/v10"
guild_id=11450093903585460254
bot_token=""
header = {
    'Authorization': f'Bot {bot_token}'
}
r=requests.get(url+f"/guilds/{guild_id}/audit-logs", headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

I tried this and it works fine, I get all the audit logs event in my server.

If I try to get the audit logs only from a specific user, I get a "Error: Bad Request".
According to https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/audit-log#get-guild-audit-log, this is what I tried:

```
import requests

url="https://discord.com/api/v10"
guild_id=11450093903585460254
bot_token=""
data={
    'user_id':'115764043842628444', #user from whom I want to get the logs
    'action_type': 12, #CHANNEL_DELETE event
    'limit': 50 #amount of audit logs event to get
}
header = {
    'Authorization': f'Bot {bot_token}'
}
r=requests.get(url+f"/guilds/{guild_id}/audit-logs", headers=header,data=data)
print(r.text)
```